# Find a harmonic function in the interior of the disk, taking values +1 and -1

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

Consider the Mobius transformation $$f(z) = \frac{1+z}{1-z}$$

Use this map to find a function $f(x,y)$ which is harmonic in $x^2+y^2<1$ and on the boundary $x^2+y^2=1$ takes values $+1$ when $y>0$ and $−1$ when $y<0$.

My work: this is part (b) of a question that I am working on.  For part (a), I described the conformal mapping, showing that it maps the unit disk to the right half-plane.

I know that $f$ harmonic means that for every $(x,y)$ in the interior of the disk, we need that $f_{xx}(x,y) + f_{yy}(x,y) = 0$. It also needs to take values +1 for $(x,y)$ on the upper semi-circle, and -1 on the lower semi-circle.

I tried writing $f(z)$ as $$f(x,y) =\frac{(1+x)+iy}{(1-x)-iy}$$

How can I proceed?

I tried setting $f(x,y) = 1$ and got the equation $2x = -2iy$.  So I made a  function $f(x,y)= 2x + i2y$, which happens to be harmonic.  But I don't know how to make it so that it takes the value $+1$ on the boundary $x^2+y^2=1$, $y>0$ (and similarly, $-1$ on the boundary $x^2+y^2=1$, $y<0$).

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How does $\log(f)$ behave, particularly on the unit circle?

Comment: Hi @WimC, this is a bit tricky, but without composing with f, I think that the complex log would turn something such as the complement of the upper unit disk ... into an upper half plane.  But you're suggesting to look at log(f), where the inputs, f(z), are already on a half-plane -- the right half-plane...

Comment: @LebronJames Yes, so how does $\log$ transform the right half plane?

Comment: Hi @WimC, I think it maps the RHP to a horizontal strip, with positive real part, and y ranging from -pi/2 to pi/2.

Comment: Hmm...the unit circle gets mapped to the imaginary axis, under the mapping of f(z).  Now, applying the complex log to the imaginary axis gives us ln|iy|+iarg(iy), which describes a horizontal strip, with positive real part, and y ranging from -pi/2 to pi/2.

Comment: Use the fact that the real and imaginary parts of an analytic function are harmonic.

Comment: Awesome hint, @zhw.  I think that, since conformal mappings preserve orientation, I see that the upper semi-circle traces out the positive imaginary axis -- from top to bottom.  Similarly the lower semi-circle, under the mapping f(z) traces out the negative imaginary axis, still from top to bottom.  Then we want these images of the upper and lower semi-circle to take values 1 and -1.  Currently, if I apply the harmonic function, Arg(w), to the image points (imaginary axis), then Arg(w) takes values +pi/2, -pi/2.

Comment: Now I can just scale Arg(w) suitably to achieve +1 and -1, namely, scaling by 2/pi gives +1 and -1, respectively.  What do you think, @zhw?  My only concern is whether a scalar-multiple of a harmonic function is again harmonic?  If so, then it looks like I am almost done.  The only thing left to do is to compute the correct inputs w, which is just an expansion of f(z) into f(x,y).  So, the harmonic function is (2/pi)*Arg(f(z)).  What are your thoughts, @zhw?  Thanks,

Comment: For completeness, choose the principal branch of Arg(w), cutting away the negative real axis; then Arg(f(z)) is single-valued and harmonic, @zhw.

Comment: using the fact that (af)' = a(f'), then we see that (a$f_{xx}+af_{yy}$) = a($f_{xx}+f_{yy}$), a (0), = 0, which shows that a scalar multiple of a harmonic function is again harmonic, @zhw :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @WimC.  I got the function (2/pi)*Arg(f(z)).  Feel free to comment further, if you think I need to do a little more work on this problem.  Have a great day, professor  :-)